# Autolisp: "While" loop with .dxf output

Tags: dxf, autolisp

I'm writing a lisp app to create 2D patterns for a CNC cutter. I have an Excel program that outputs 3-10 short lisp subroutines for individual pieces associated with each pattern, and I can get any number of these subs to *load* inside my "while" loop and draw the piece, but none of the methods I can get working to *create* .dxf files from the drawings generated by one of the pattern subs will let me resume the loop. If I pull out the dxfout and erase steps and just let them all draw on top of one another, it works like a charm.

```
(defun c:CreateDXF (/ owd ofd sdate)

  (setq owd (acet-file-cwd))
  (acet-file-chdir "P:\\")
  (setq ofd (getvar "filedia"))
  (setvar "filedia" 0)

  (setq sdate (getstring "\nEnter the order start date in YYYYMMDD format: "))

  (setq fpath (strcat "P:\\LSP\\" sdate))
  (setq wopath (acet-ui-pickdir "Select Work Order Folder" fpath))
  (setq flist (vl-directory-files wopath "*.lsp" 1))

  (while (> (length flist) 0)
    (setq fname (car flist))
    (setq wfile (strcat wopath "\\" fname))
    (vl-file-rename wfile "P:\\LSP\\temp.lsp")
    (load "P:\\LSP\\temp.lsp")
    (vl-file-rename "P:\\LSP\\temp.lsp" wfile)

    (setq savepath (strcat "P:\\DXF\\" sdate))
    (setq savename (strcat (vl-filename-base wfile) ".dxf"))

    (setq patt (ssget "x"))

    (command "_.dxfout" savepath "_Objects" patt "" "_Version" "2013" "16" "" "")

    (command "erase" "all" "")
    (setq flist (cdr flist))

    );while

  (acet-file-chdir owd)
  (setvar "filedia" ofd)

  (alert "Done")
  (princ)

);defun
```

Running this as written hangs up at the first dxfout step. I can reset the program through the lisp editor, and then file appears in the output directory and the dxf comes up in a new tab, but obviously that exits the loop without processing the rest of the pieces.

Am I missing something obvious? Would it be better to draw all of the pattern pieces in the same drawing as named entities and then batch out each entity at the end?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to approach this from outside of AutoCAD.  Maybe using a PowerShell script to fetch the .dwg files list, open AutoCAD, then loop through the drawing list, export the .dxf, close the .dwg and do the next, then close AutoCAD.